# Prevent MP3 to Play and Start Downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

```
  window.location.href = 'filename.mp3';
```

I am using javascript to start download MP3 File Download automatically. But it keeps on playing in the browser.
Is there any way to start downloading and prevent it to play in browser...

Thanks,

Comment: Short answer, no. Not a clean , js only, cross browser compatible way. And some users don't like force downloads, either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force+download

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.downloadFile = function (sUrl) {
        window.open(sUrl, '_self');
    }
    window.downloadFile("filename.mp3");
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the MIME type of the response to  application/octet-stream

Answer (score -1):

Though not really javascript, but what about using the new ["download" attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) of the `<a>` tag?

To automatically trigger such a "click" in javascript, you can use jQuery to build a new DOM anchor obejct with `.attr('download', true)` and "click" it then. It depends on your actual needs, how to implement that nicely.

*edit: remove apache stuff*